# Iterating over one dimension of array until a value found

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array as follows

`$array[$id][$iterator][test1][test2][a][b][c][d]`

I would like to test for each `$iterator` for the first instance of `test1=not null` (if so use a, b, c d)
 else use the first instance of  `test2=not null` use (a, b, c, d)
else use "---"

I don't know how to get a loop to break on first instance of a finding `test1` and `test2` or if there is a better construct to use than a loop in this case?

Comment: show the initial array content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To break an iteration or loop

Just tell it to take a break :)

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item == 'I the great overlord command you to stop iterating!') {
        break;
    }
}
```

#### If you wanna...

if you just want to know if a certain value is in your array, you can do it like this:

```
if (in_array('The value you are looking for', $thatArrayItShouldBeIn)) {
    die("Its in! Its in! Yippie!");
}
```

#### From the comments

Tell me if I'm wrong, but from your comment I come to understand you want your iteration to break at a certain loop?

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    // Keys start at 0, so the first item is 0
    if ($key == 3) {
        // We'll stop looping at the 4th iteration
        break;
    }
}
```

#### Taking yet another look

If you really have an array with alot of layers and you just want to check one value for each iteration you can just do:

```
foreach ($array[$id]['iterator'] as $item) {
    if ($item['test1'] == true) {
        // Do something
    }
}    }
```

Comment: I deleted the old comment.  To be more clear...`foreach $array[$id]['iterator'] as item......if $array[$id][$item]['test1']=true //do something` will this work?